# Remove Cent OS 7 from a server

Tags: linux, centos7

I have a server that has CentOS 6.5 and 7 installed on separate partition. I would like to remove the CentOS 7 version. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Fdisk to remove the partition that has centos7? Or do you need to keep the other partition?

Comment: I would like to remove only CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [dd(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dd)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of =/dev/partition/withc7 bs=1024m count=N
```

where N is the number of GB of the C7 cartition.

Comment: Can I use this command while booted into the CentOS 6.5?